# How to check React browser compatibility(generic) on load to avoid blank screen

Tags: html, reactjs, cross-browser, modernizr

Few users reporting they see blank screen with no proper information in some old browsers, so is there any way we can check the browser compatibility and pass on the issue information ?

I tried reading Agent but i may need to hardcode the version. Is there any generic way to accomplish it ?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but you might be able to get some mileage out of https://polyfill.io/v3/ for a quick fix for those users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check browser compatibility using User agent is not a good way and it will not be generic as we decide the browser version and allow.

Solution is widely used Modernizr tool, a JS library which allows us to check compatibility based on features support.